# how to use oracle sequence in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, sequence, dual-table

i am trying to access the below sql to generate the next sequence number. i am getting **QuerySyntaxException caused by dual is not mapped.**

sql = Select sequence_caseid.NEXTVAL from DUAL

```
public Long generate(Session session)
    throws DataRetrievalFailureException, SQLDataException {
    Long result = null;
    Query<?> query = (Query) session.createQuery(sql);
    result = new Long(query.getFirstResult());
    return result;
}
```

bean definition for generators

```
<bean id="generatorVoucherId" class="com.sample.OracleSequenceGenerator">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"><value>${logger.name}</value></constructor-arg>
        <property name="generatorName"><value>sequence_caseid</value></property>
</bean>
```

i dont have an hbm.xml for this dual. Do i need one? if so how to create one? i have multiple sequence generators in oracle like this, can i make one for all of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `createNativeQuery` method to execute SQL.